# strtotime +1 month goes past the next month

Tags: php, date, increment, strtotime, date-range

When using `strtotime()` to add one month, it gives me wrong output in a condition where I put date "2017-01-30"

```
function date_diff($min,$max)
{
    $d1 = strtotime($min);
    $d2 = strtotime($max);
    $min_date = min($d1, $d2);
    $max_date = max($d1, $d2);
    $count=$i = 0;
    while (($min_date = strtotime("+1 MONTH", $min_date)) <= $max_date)
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        echo date('Y-m-d',$min_date)."--------".date("Y-m-d",$max_date);
    }

}
```

I am calling the function with dates like this:

```
date_diff("2016/12/30","2017/07/30");
```

The output from above function is:

```
2017-01-30--------2017-07-30
2017-03-02--------2017-07-30 // wrong calculation on this line
2017-04-02--------2017-07-30
2017-05-02--------2017-07-30
2017-06-02--------2017-07-30
2017-07-02--------2017-07-30
```

Expected output

```
2017-01-31--------2017-07-30
2017-02-28--------2017-07-30
2017-03-31--------2017-07-30
2017-04-30--------2017-07-30
2017-05-31--------2017-07-30
2017-06-30--------2017-07-30
```

Comment: Because there isn't a February 30th, so it adds 30 days, wich becomes march 2nd.

Comment: What output do you expect? Feb 30 doesn't exist

Comment: yeah i know what is the solution

Comment: i want to add one month in any date is it possible in php

Comment: First of all code will give `Cannot re declare date_diff() in .....`. Alos in feb 28 or 29 days will be there so when you add one month to jan (30 days) it will come as 1 march or 2 march

Comment: @Shahneel Ahmed yes you can add 1 month to any date like:

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 month")); here we are adding 1 month in current date

Comment: To add one month, use this code: echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2017-01-30")+strtotime("+1 month", "2017-01-30"));

Comment: The code you have written works as expected.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: what is your expected output is question which force me to think like i was not thinking

Comment: @BunkerBoy i can add one month or i can add 30 days

Comment: Since 2017-02-30 doesn't exist. After add one month to 2017-01-30, you will get 2017-03-02. Which you are getting.

Comment: @ Shahneel Ahmed you can add both 30 day or 1 month both will give same output try like : echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 month")); echo "<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 30 day"));

Comment: okw thanks for your help @KalyanSrinivasLimkar bunker boy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (likely even) that I am misunderstanding your question, but here is my shot at providing an answer.

Code:

```
function date_func($d1,$d2){
    $min=date("Y-m-t",strtotime(min([$d1,$d2])));  // always the last day of the month
    $max=date("Y-m-d",strtotime(max([$d1,$d2])));
    $month_count=0;
    while(($min=date("Y-m-t",strtotime("$min +1 day")))<$max){
        ++$month_count;
        echo "$min--------$max\n";
    }
    echo "Month Count: $month_count\n";  // I assume you only want the count at the end
}
date_func("2016/12/30","2017/07/30");  // I had to rename your function to avoid an error
```

Output:

```
2017-01-31--------2017-07-30
2017-02-28--------2017-07-30
2017-03-31--------2017-07-30
2017-04-30--------2017-07-30
2017-05-31--------2017-07-30
2017-06-30--------2017-07-30
Month Count: 6
```

Comment: got output thanks solved my problem thanks @mickmackusa

Answer (score 1):

> Find the difference in month and then use mktime

```
$min="2016/12/30";
$max="2017/07/30";
 $ts1 = strtotime($max);
 $ts2 = strtotime($min);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

$diff = (($year1 - $year2) * 12) + ($month1 - $month2);

for ($i = 1; $i < $diff; $i++)
        {
             $last_day=date('m-t-Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, $year1))));
            echo $last_day."--------".date('Y-m-d',$ts1);
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

Output

```
01-31-2017--------2017-07-30
02-28-2017--------2017-07-30
03-31-2017--------2017-07-30
04-30-2017--------2017-07-30
05-31-2017--------2017-07-30
06-30-2017--------2017-07-30
```

Comment: i want to check how many month different between two dates but also validate that interval should be a number not float

Comment: for example 2017-07-30 to 2018-01-30 is ok but 2017-07-30 to 2018-02-03 is not okw